# NAudio recording is somewhere filtering the high frequencies?

Tags: c#, matlab, signal-processing, audio-recording, naudio

I am recording freqs like 17k and try to decode them with Goertzel filters.

I think NAdio is filtering some high freqs although there are no filters at all in my program.

I recorded the same sound file with Audacity and see a fine spectrum.

[image]

Now, I do the same thing with my c# program with this kind of code of recording the sound:

```
void myWaveIn_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        myMemoryStream.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);//this is for playing the myMemoryStream
        for (int index = 0; index < e.BytesRecorded; index += 2)//Here I convert in a loop the stream into floating number samples
        {

            short sample = (short)((e.Buffer[index + 1] << 8) |
                                    e.Buffer[index + 0]);
            samples32Extended.Add(sample);
            samples32.Add(sample / 32768f);//IEEE 32 floating number 
        }
    }
```

Then, I generate a binary file in order to read it in MATLAB to see its spectrum like that:

```
float[] samples32array = samples32.ToArray();
        using(BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("C:/Users/alon/Desktop/myRecordings/myRecordBin.bin", FileMode.Create)))
        {
            foreach (var value in samples32array)
            {
                writer.Write(value);
            }
        }
```

Then, the spectrum by matlab is like that:

[image]

I don't have a clue of what is happening.. Must get a help from you.. thanks

Comment: I would first compare NAudio and Audacity using white or pink noise. That would at least tell what kind of filtering is applied.

Comment: One plot is voltage/amplitude while the other is power.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just saw it ...

Comment: hello, I edited the second plot and you can see that after 1.5*10^4 the freq I looking for is nothing but 0.

Comment: I recommend you try to use you'r own filter instead of Goertzel. You can design it and make a differential equation from it (later I can do it for you). We will need only a measured vector (this recorded sound) and then we can filter frequencies that we want.

Comment: Instead of using a linear Y scale use a log scale like 20log(y);  Also change x axis use positive frequencies.

Comment: NAudio isn't doing any filtering, it's simply returning the samples from the WaveIn APIs. What sample rate are you recording at?

Comment: Hello Mark: 44100 samp/sec